# proof verification of the measurability of the sets of all points where a sequence $f_{n}$ converges.

Tags: measure-theory

Someone can help me to verifying if the following reasoning it right?. Somebody read my proof and told me that there is a problem with the choose of the epsilon. If so, any one can clarify to me the mistake.

My proof is the following:

We can write
$$
A = \{x \in X: \lim_{n}f_{n}(x) \text{ exists}\} = \{x \in X: \{f_{n}(x)\} \text{is a Cauchy sequence}\}.
$$
Let $\epsilon >0. $Define the sets $A_{m,n}(\epsilon) = \{x \in X: \lvert f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x) \lvert < \epsilon.\}$. This sets are measurable since the functions $f_{n} - f_{m}$ are measurable.

So, $x \in A$ if and only  there exists $N$ such that for $m,n \geq N$ $\lvert f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x) \rvert  < \epsilon$, that is to say, if only if
$$
x \in \bigcap_{m,n \geq N} A_{m,n} (\epsilon),
$$
and we have this if and only if
$$
x \in \bigcup_{p = 1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m,n \geq  p}^{\infty} A_{m,n}(\epsilon).
$$
Then we have that
$$
A = \bigcup_{p = 1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m,n \geq p}^{\infty} A_{m,n}(\epsilon).
$$
We conclude that $A$ is measurable.

Comment: Alternative: $A = \{x \in X : \limsup f_n = \liminf f_n\}$. $\limsup f_n$ and $\liminf f_n$ are easily shown to be measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this property for all $\varepsilon>0$ so you have another big intersection over all $\varepsilon>0$. It suffices to take $\varepsilon\in ]0,\infty[\cap\Bbb Q$ and the intersection becomes countable, i.e.
$$
A = \bigcap_{\varepsilon\in ]0,\infty[\cap\Bbb Q} \bigcup_{N\in\Bbb N} \bigcap_{n,m\geq N} A_{n,m}(\varepsilon).
$$

A bit more details maybe: $(f_n(x))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for fixed $x$ is a Cauchy sequence iff
$$
(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists N_\varepsilon\in\Bbb N)(\forall m,n\geq N_\varepsilon)\ \ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Since this expression forces the condition you stated for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have this other big intersection. The reason we can take it as rational number is since for all $r\in]0,\infty[$ we find a rational $0<q\leq r$. The property $\ldots < q$ is at least as strong as $\ldots <r$.

**Edit:**

The problem is, that in your construction you fixed some $\varepsilon >0$. This is arbitrary, yes, but your sets still depend on it. If you write down the sets step by step you (hopefully) see it:
\begin{align*}
A_{m,n}(\varepsilon) &= \{x\in X : |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon\}\\
B(N_\varepsilon,\varepsilon) &= \{x\in X : (\forall m,n \geq N_\varepsilon)\ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \varepsilon \} = \bigcap_{m,n\geq N_\varepsilon} A_{m,n}(\varepsilon)\\
C(\varepsilon) &= \{x\in X : (\exists N_\varepsilon \in\Bbb N) (\forall m,n\geq N_\varepsilon)\ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon\} = \bigcup_{N_\varepsilon\in\Bbb N} B(N_\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\\
A &= \{x\in X : (\forall \varepsilon > 0) (\exists N_\varepsilon\in \Bbb N)(\forall m,n \geq N_\varepsilon)\ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \varepsilon\} = \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} C(\varepsilon)
\end{align*}
The sets $C(\varepsilon)$ you defined (especially the $N=N_\varepsilon$) actually depend on $\varepsilon > 0$. To get the condition for Cauchy sequences at $x$, you need to intersect all these sets.

Comment: Hi. I have shown that $A = \cup \cap A_{m,n}(\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. What you tell me would be intersect $A$ infinitely many times with $A$ itself. I don't see why this is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I understand the mistake. We need intersect over $\epsilon$. Thanks.

Comment: I just added some more details to my answer. Hopefully they will make everything clear now.